# Cant invoke a function using template variable

Tags: angular, typescript

```
@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  ...
})
export class SimpleModal {
  modalOpen: boolean;

  isModalOpen(): boolean {
    return this.modalOpen;
  }
}
```

```
<modal #modalRef>
  <div *ngIf="modalRef.isModalOpen()">...</div>
</modal>
```

Error (tests):
`TypeError: jit_nodeValue_9(...).isModalOpen is not a function`

I'm guessing that those function weren't created yet? There is no problem to check `*ngIf="modalRef.modalOpen` but what if `modalOpen` was a private field? Do I Have to create an external method in component that uses the modal to check there by ViewChild whether the modal is open?

Comment: You can wrap your child component inside a div and put the *ngIf in that div, I dont see a reason why it should be here.

Comment: @elzoy are you trying to create a custom reusable modal  component

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to create a stub component for the modal and declare it in spec file.